# Unable to attatch image to pug html and nodemailer

Tags: node.js, automation, pug, attachment, nodemailer

We have tested this many ways and I'm curious if we would have to add anything to the  interface EmailOptions<T:any>. When the email is sent we only see the alternative from the file not rendering.

```
     interface EmailOptions<T = any> {
        /**
         * The template name
         */
        template?: string;
        /**
         * Nodemailer Message <Nodemailer.com/message/>
         *
         * Overrides what is given for constructor
         */
        message?: Mail.Options;
        /**
         * The Template Variables
         */
        locals?: T;
          ///do we need attachments?:someObj; here?
    }
```

This is the absolute path to the image file.
packages/api/image/header.jpg

This is the absolute path to the mailer file.
packages/api/helper/mailer.js

```
This is the html.pug
img(src= 'header.jpg' alt='header' style='width:100%; height:auto;')
```

```
This is the email method
function sendSurveyEmail(application) {
  email.send({
    template: 'survey',
    message: {
      from: 'Person <person@email.org>',
      to: 'Other@person.io'
    },
    locals: {
      name: application.thisName,
      patientName: application.thatName,
      appUrl: process.env.APP_URL,
    },
    attachments: [{
      filename: 'header.jpg',
      path: '.public/image/header.jpg',
      cid: 'header.jpg' 
  }]
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
  .then(() => console.log('email has been sent!'));
}
```

Comment: file:///private/var/folders/kw/jlnbwxq14nz519nplxw8dry80000gn/T/1cfc1dae-4cda-417e-9520-0fb57bdbba10.html                   
      This is the source file from the inspector.

Comment: Is there another aspect of this mailer i need to add to this question to better describe the error? I am open to advice to better communicate this error.